# How to Sterilize Bung and Hole while Maintaining a Strong Seal?

Tags: mead, airlock

How do you sanitize and prepare a bung for stopping a carboy? While making sure that it will maintain a good seal and not *POP* off sometime later.

**In depth**
I removed and sterilized my bung and airlock (from a 170 day batch of JAOM) last night (due to a fruit fly infestation of the lock: [Q: Fruit Flies in Airlock](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9937/fruit-flies-in-airlock-how-can-i-test-if-mead-is-okay)).

I had a difficult time replacing the bung after sterilizing it with Star San sanitize. My right brain wanted to dry the bung and bung hole with a paper towel while my left brain believed this would lead to possible contamination.

I eventually air-dried the bung in my hand, fearful of contaminating it if I let it rest anywhere. After a few attempts the bung appeared to fit into place. I affixed the airlock and cleaned up. I went to bed 90 minutes later, all appeared fine. However, when I woke this morning I noticed the bung and airlock *POPPED* off!

This time I just placed the bung into the hole and topped off my airlock. I cannot help but feel that I do not know what I am doing, that I have bought an inferior bung, or that my mead is now on a dooms day count down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paper towels right off the roll are sanitary, so you could have dried things with them.  I have done that many times without a problem.  I have also used duct tape to hold the stopper in the carboy.

Comment: I've also used zip ties. You can also buy a carboy cap instead.